# Cannot find module './collection/batch/unordered' - Node JS on Heroku

Tags: node.js, mongodb, heroku

I have a problem that is driving me crazy for two days now. I have deployed a node app on heroku that worked well. Two days ago, I did an update of my modules (I am not 100% sure it is directly linked to my problem), and since I keep getting this message on my logs :

```
             Error: Cannot find module './collection/batch/unordered'
                  at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:338:15)
                  at Function.Module._load (module.js:280:25)
                  at Module.require (module.js:364:17)
                  at require (module.js:380:17)
                  at Object.<anonymous> (/app/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongodb/collection.js:21:17)
                  at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)
                  at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
                  at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
                  at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
                  at Module.require (module.js:364:17)
              Failed to load c++ bson extension, using pure JS version
```

Locally, the app works perfectly.

I tried to change versions back to what it was, without success.

So I checked in node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongodb, and indeed I did not find the "batch" folder and thus the unordered.js file, required by the node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongodb/collection.js file.

I tried to uninstall and re install mongodb. The batch folder and the unordered.js did appear. But the error still remains. And if I re deploy on Heroku, the batch folder is missing again.

I have strictly no idea what to try now, and I would deeply appreciate some help. Thank you !

EDIT :

Here is my packages.json :

```
  {
    "name": "Killerapp",
    "version": "0.0.1",
    "private": true,
    "scripts": {
    "start": "node app.js"
   },
    "engines": {
       "node": "0.10.26" 
    },
    "dependencies": {
       "express": "3.5.1",
       "ejs" : "~0.8.5",
       "mongodb": "1.4.2",
       "mongoose": "3.8.8",
       "connect-mongo": "*", 
       "passport" : "~0.1.17",     
       "connect-flash" : "~0.1.1",   
       "bcrypt-nodejs" : "latest",
       "moment" : "latest"
       }
     }
```

Comment: Ok, I found a dirty solution. I removed my node_modules from my gitignore and I directly pushed my modules on Heroku. That is probably not the best solution, but it works...

Answer (score 0):

Is there a reason you have hardcoded a version of `mongodb` in your dependencies? I believe mongoose will pull in the right version...

Try removing `mongodb` from your package.json, remove your `node_modules` from git, then push to heroku.